# JProfiler: bandwidth requirement for remote profiling over VPN

Tags: jprofiler

We are planning to use JProfiler to profile several live application deployed in our clients' DC.
What would be the required bandwidth to allow smooth profiling session?

Comment: Also, is it OK to have 1 JProfiler license and have many agents installed in remote machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bandwidth required between the JProfiler GUI and the agent is quite low, it only requests the data that has to be displayed, not the entire profiling data.

The entire profiling data is only transmitted when you save a snapshot.

> Also, is it OK to have 1 JProfiler license and have many agents installed in remote machines?

Yes, you only need a license for the JProfiler GUI, not for the profiling agent.